# MySQL Error - Unknown column - need to edit

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Thanks for reading.

Reading through all the articles on here helped me locate my problem, I'm just not sure how I should edit the code. I still learning.

The message I get is:

```
SELECT attachid
FROM ilace_attachment WHERE attachtype = 'ads' AND user_id ='6' AND ads_id='1'


MySQL Error  : Unknown column 'ads_id' in 'where clause'
Error Number : 1054
```

This all started after I upgrade my software script to a newer version. I checked the ads_ads in MYSQL and there isn't a colum for ads_id, just one called; id.

I believe the solution to my problem is to change the "ads_id" to just "id". But I'm not sure if thats right or what I should change.

```
  $sql = $ilace->db->query("SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE '". DB_PREFIX ."ads_ads'");
  $ads_id_temp = $ilace->db->fetch_array($sql);
  $ads_id=$ads_id_temp['Auto_increment'];
}
else
{
  $ads_id=$ilace->GPC['id'];
}
$attachid = $ilace->db->fetch_field(DB_PREFIX . "attachment", "attachtype = '".'ads'."' AND user_id ='".$_SESSION['ilacedata']['user']['userid']."' AND ads_id='".$ads_id."'", "attachid");
```

Here is the script it runs.

```
http//wwwWEBSITEcom/campaign.php?id=0&cmd=_create-    campaign&1=Advertise+here+for+%245.00+per+1000+views&2=Targeted+AdTITLENAME+adverts&3=http%3A%2F%2FwwwWEBSITEcom%2Fcampaign.php%3Fcmd%3Dcreate%26mode%3Dppc&4=Vist&zone=header&mode=PPI&clicks=0&5=1&keywords=KEYWORD1%2C+was%2C+KEYWORD2%2C+KETWORD3%2C+KEYWORD4&dotw[1]=1&dotw[2]=1&dotw[3]=1&dotw[4]=1&dotw[5]=1&dotw[6]=1&dotw[0]=1
```

Comment: This means exactly what the error is saying.  You have no column titled 'ads_id'.  At least not at that level.

Comment: is the name of the column ads_id if it is try doing this `ads_id`=1

Comment: So, create the `ads_id` column.

Answer (score 1):

You change `AND ads_id=` to `AND id=` because that is the field name in the SQL statement, and seemingly the field name has changed. 
You do not change `$ads_id` because that is the name of your PHP variable, and this works fine as it is and does not need to be the same as the field name.

On a wider level, you should sit and figure out how the last line of the PHP quoted puts together the SQL statement quoted in the error. You should know that the `.` is used to concatenate strings together, that PHP strings must start and end with the same character but that can be either `'` or `"`, and that the SQL statement requires `'` around values.

Also, if you've updated a third-party software script and it's now incompatible with your database you should look to see if there was some sort of data migration script that you've not run.

Comment: I tried changing the and ads_id= to id=. But didnt work. here is what it said.

Comment: MySQL Error  : Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'
Error Number : 1054

Comment: You previously said "I checked the ads_ads in MYSQL and there isn't a colum for ads_id, just one called; id."
I've looked again at your post and I realise the table is actually `attachment`. What is the ID field called in that table?

Comment: I have "user_id" in that table.

Comment: Er, we know that. What are all the columns in the `ilace_attachment` table? There probably should be an `ads_id` column in there but I have no idea what this script is doing. Please read the last para of my answer if you haven't already.

Comment: Hi Paul, Thanks you for all your help this far. I added the script to my question above. I did read your hole answer a few times, However, I am new to php coding and I'm just trying to understand. At this point, I believe that I should create a column for ads_id. But I have never done that before. Will adding the column effect anything? Is there anything I should know before I try? will it effect the rest of my site by adding it? Thanks much!

Comment: If you just create the `ads_id` column, the query won't fall over, but then again it will never find an `attachid` unless you also start saving something into `ads_id` that matches what it is looking for.

I don't really understand how you got to this point. When you said "I upgrade[d] my software script to a newer version", where did you get that script from? Do they offer support?

Answer (score 0):

Depends. Is the id column containing the same information as ads_id? If so, yes you should change it. If no, you should figure out what happened to the ids and why they were removed.

Comment: Hello. This script worked fine before the upgrade. I didn't change anything with the DB when I upgraded it, just the site files. My question was what part of the code should I change if ads_id needs to be just id? everything that says ads_id to just id? You you show me an example code?